# Dynamically changing chart data using Django and Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts

How would I go about allowing a user to change the status of a  graph and updating it on the page?

For example, allowing a user to adjust the size of a graph without having to rePOST.

I am using High charts in Django, what I have thought about doing is this. Send all the data over, and set a default size so that there is something to display. Then add a dropdown or something that allows the user to increase the size of the graph. When a user selects one of them, I somehow slice the data to increase the size.

E.g., list L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] is sent over, but the default size is 5. So only L[:5] is displayed. The user selects the size to be 6, so it reloads so that L[:6] is displayed.

Example graph:

[image: Example graph]

Below are code snippets of my class based view. A user searches the reddit user he/she wants to analyse -> data is collected, fun things happen and all charts are set up ->

```
def post(self, request): 
   ...

   top_chart_series = collected user data, ready to be parsed in JS. 
   # currently I am only sending over the default size of data (top 10 words)
   # but what I would like to do is send ALL of the data and then deal with it in JS. 
   return render(request, <htmlpage.html>, .... lots of variables, {'top_chart_series': top_chart_series...}) 


.... to the JS 
# So this is where I am a bit confused.
# At this point, the page is being loaded and the charts are being set up via JS: 
# My question then, is how can I allow the user to adjust the size of the graph without having
# to rePOST? 
# I lack JS knowledge so that is probably why I am so confused in how I can approach this.

# Anyway, what I was thinking was, once ALL the data is sent, I first chart a graph
# with the default size (10 words), and then if the user decides to adjust the data
# I run the function again(?) with the selected size. 
# Here is the JS that I use currently, I haven't implemented anything I have described.


            function top_words(target, title, categories, data){
            // The parameters are variables sent in by django
            // E.g., top_words('#top_chart', 'Top Words', '{{ top_chart_series.categories|safe }}','{{ top_chart_series.data|safe }}');
            var seriesOptions = JSON.parse(data);
            var categories = JSON.parse(categories);

            $(target).highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    categories: categories
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                    text: 'Occurence'
                    }
                },
                exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        showInLegend: false 
                    }
                },

                series: seriesOptions
            }
        );
```

Comment: It's not unclear what you're saying, it just unclear what you want (doesn't seem like you quite know yourself either). You need to define more specifically what you need, so we can give a specific answer back. However, everything you're suggesting seems perfectly doable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! No, I do know what I want to do, I probably should of went in more detail. I am building a reddit analysis web app, and one of the graphs that is included is the users top used words out of his comments. The user of the app searches a reddit user, the POST is sent -> in the backend, data is collected.. etc. All I want is to be able to allow the user to update the graph (increase the size of the word graph) once the search has been done.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Well, it still seems sort of open for discussion (which SO isn't meant for), but I'd start off by having the dropdown and chart ready. Highcharts is very versatile, so editing the data on that end shouldn't be a problem, either dynamically or the viewing of static data. You might get some other opinions though (which is why this is borderline SO question).

Comment: I have everything finished. I just want to implement the dynamic adjustment. Here's an example btw: http://i.imgur.com/F0BylrB.png

Comment: Ah okay. Well, then I suggest setting up an example with code and what exact part you are having trouble with so it's easier to go into the details. You have to be stuck before we can give exact pointers on how a given issue can be resolved.

Comment: No problem, I'll get it up in a second.

Comment: Looks much better! I'll dig in a little later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: Alright, appreciate it!

Comment: I guess you want something like that? http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077. Bad part is that it is using angular and d3js but hope it can give you an idea (changing d3js for highcharts). I'm a beginner in angularjs and I successfully connected the chart with my Django backend.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I managed to get it working. I found HighCharts addPoint() function and went from there.